# Creating YAML configuration files (parsed via as3yaml) instead of XML, in an Actionscript project

Tags: actionscript-3, parsing, yaml, configuration-files

Has anyone used the as3yaml YAML parser for Actionscript? I have an Actionscript application (authored in the Flash IDE, not Flash Builder), which parses an XML configuration file on startup. I'd like to replace this with an easier-to-read YAML file, but I'm concerned that the as3yaml parser won't be as reliable as Actionscript's built-in XML parser. Has anyone used as3yaml or do you know of a better YAML parser for Actionscript?

http://code.google.com/p/as3yaml/

Thanks!

Comment: There are a [few others](https://github.com/search?l=ActionScript&p=1&q=yaml+as3) out there.

Comment: I have a project with xml config >4k lines. Just tried to convert it to YAML. Building XML was about 30ms in debugger, decoding YAML with as3yaml took about 10 seconds. So I decided not to switch to YAML, though it looks pretty good agains xml.

Comment: I had one yaml config for 3 project modules: flash, PHP and java. So my build script generated Config.as file for flash module and other config files for other modules :)